# Does "how dare you" imply a question?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-requests

To say "how come you (didn't shut the fridge)?" or "how did you (forget to call)?" implies an obvious question.

So my question is: does "how dare you" mean why do you feel so emboldened to do so and so?

Comment: It's an exclamation, a rhetorical question perhaps. How wonderful. How marvelous. After I washed the floor, darn it, how could you?

Comment: IMO "how dare you" is a complaint, not a question, although the circumstances might suggest an explanation is expected, not an answer to the direct question.

Comment: So similar to seeing something out of the ordinary and saying "wow, what a trip"? Also never considered the rhetorical, that checks out, thanks

Comment: So context can change what the person saying it is implying, sounds right too, thanks

Comment: @WeatherVane, it is indeed a complaint, and not a **genuine** question (i.e. no answer is expected), but it still has the form of a question. It is a rhetorical question of sorts, in that the expectation is that, as soon as it is asked, it will be realised that, whatever the answer is, it can't possibly justify what was done.

Comment: It's entirely rhetorical, and archaic too. Modern English would say _How do you dare?_, but this phrase was formed back while _dare_ was more modal than it is today.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't see it as archaic in UK. There was fairly recent TV show where one character's catch-phrase was the ungrammatical "How very dare you?"

Comment: @WeatherVane What's archaic about it is using it without *do* support, like *What think you?* or *How came you?* Do you see why such formulations are “archaic” in today’s English? That happens only with verbs that are already auxiliaries, including modals: *What more need she do?*

Comment: @tchrist what I meant is that if people are saying it, then it isn't archaic. I do hear this *particular* exclamation, although I agree with your "What think you?" and others.

Comment: For me, as for many other people, _dare_ is a semi-modal. Thus _I daren't_ is far more natural to me than _I don't dare_. I _think_ that I would also say _Dare you talk to him?_  (but it's notoriously difficult to be sure exactly what one would say "in the wild"). On the other hand, in the past I would say _I didn't dare_.

Comment: @NorCalNate - in "wow, what a trip", the 'what' has nothing to do with a question.

Comment: I haven't checked, but I expect that the exclamation mark will appear more often than the question mark in most examples where X is non-zero ("How dare you X") on the internet. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/how-dare-you) for instance has << How dare you pick up the phone and listen in on my conversations! >>

Answer (score 4):

On the one hand, the expression "how dare you?" is clearly a rhetorical question—that is, it isn't a question in search of an answer, like "how hot is it today?" but (in this case) an interrogatively framed expression of anger or outrage in response to an offensive action or statement by "you." In effect, the expression "how dare you [do or say X]?" amounts to saying "I find it [your action or statement X] unacceptable and intolerable."

On the other hand—perhaps in part because of its interrogative form—"how dare you?" issues a personalized verbal challenge that at some level invites a response: "How dare you?" hangs in the air in a way that "That's outrageous!" doesn't.

Most dictionaries of idioms don't mention "how dare you" as an idiomatic form. However, *Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms* (2003) has this entry:

> **how dare you *do sth*** *esp. spoken* I am very surprised and shocked by what you are doing | *How dare you show up at my wedding?* USAGE: usually shows that you think someone's behavior is very wrong: *How dare he accuse of us of lying?*

So my answer to the posted title of this question, is yes, "how dare you?" arguably does imply a question—a rhetorical one, at any rate—but it does not imply any doubt as to the speaker's verdict that the conduct or speech under discussion is utterly inappropriate.